# Cookie clicker game multiple variable shop

Tags: javascript, html

I am new here just starting with coding and after few learning days I decidet to put the code into a good use. I started with cookie clicker like game but with a difference. I have multiple resources (oil, gold). I made a big progress but then I waned to make shop. But not normal shop with some items that boost your gains but something for wars (which I don´t have yet so I just want it to be a counter for now), the thing is that it uses multiple resources (gold, oil) I took the code for production boosting of those materials and changed it so that it consumes both resources. But now it goes under 0 which is bad. I spend like 1.5 hour on these 6 lines of code like an idiot and I hope that you can help me. 
So this is the button which I think works fine

```
<button onclick="automobily()"><p id="cars1"></p></button>
```

This should be what is written on the button (at least I figurated it out it should)

```
document.getElementById("cars1").innerHTML = "Car (0) 100 oil and 50 gold";
```

And this is the problem...

```
function automobily() {
if (oil >= 100 + (cars1))  (gold >= 50 + (cars1)); {
gold -= 50 ;oil -= 100 ;cars1 += 1
carcost = 50    
document.getElementById("oil").innerHTML = oil;
document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
document.getElementById("cars1").innerHTML = "cars (" + cars1 + ")" + carcost + " 100 oil and 50 gold";

}
}
```

It should work fine... (at least I hope so)
So the main problem is that it goes negative. Please also note that I am a begginer and I don´t understand all the coding terms so if you can explain it a bit mor einto depth. Thanks in advance.
-Holsp

PS: This is the code to run it.

```
    <big><b><h1>Gold</h1></b></big>

<img src="mince.png" alt="mince" style="width:180px;height:180px;border:0;" onclick="clickme()" />

<h2><bold><big>You have <element id="gold"></element> grams of gold</big></bold></h2>

<p id="gold"></p><br><br>
<script>
gold = 0;
cps = 0;
autoGs = 0;
employGs = 0;
clicker = 1;
adminGs = 0;
function clickme() {
gold += clicker;
document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
}
</script>

<br></br>
<img src="barel.png" alt="Barel" style="width:200px;height:180px;border:0;" onclick="clickme1()" />

<h2><bold><big>You have <element id="oil"></element> barrels of oil</big></bold></h2>

<script>
oil = 0;
cps1 = 0;
bakers1 = 0;
godlybakers1 = 0;
clicker1 = 1;
gloves1 = 0;
function clickme1() {
oil += clicker1;
document.getElementById("oil").innerHTML = oil;
}
</script>

<button onclick="automobily()"><p id="cars1"></p></button>

<script>
document.getElementById("cars1").innerHTML = "Car (0) 100 oil and 50 gold";

function automobily() {
    if (oil >= 100 + (cars1))  (gold >= 50 + (cars1)); {
    gold -= 50 ;oil -= 100 ;cars1 += 1
    carcost = 50    
    document.getElementById("oil").innerHTML = oil;
    document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
    document.getElementById("cars1").innerHTML = "cars (" + cars1 + ")" + carcost + " 100 oil and 50 gold";

    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So what is expected behavior? Don't feel bad about spending all that time....leaning to code does take time and the initial learning curve is steep. I'm sure you learned a lot ...regardless of whether it works or not yet

Comment: Also if you provide the minimal basic html for this would help us be able to run the code. Take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: added the code to the question

Comment: @charlietfl you got it

Comment: OK. Just missing what is expected when something gets to zero

Comment: @charlietfl I don´t want it to go under zero. Just for it to stay there. It worked with one material but with both it just goes down

Comment: Not sure what `if (oil >= 100 + (cars1))  (gold >= 50 + (cars1)); {` is supposed to do. First has syntax error which will throw exception error which you can see in browser dev tools console(F12). Those errors are first place to start debugging. Is missing an operator between the 2 statements like `&&'(AND) or `||`(OR)

Comment: I used && but with the same result... I am not good at using those symbols

Comment: @charlietfl so, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing your condition to this solve that:

```
if ( (oil >= 100 + (cars1)) && (gold >= 50 + (cars1)) )
```

Full Code

```js
oil = 0;
cps1 = 0;
bakers1 = 0;
godlybakers1 = 0;
clicker1 = 1;
gloves1 = 0;

function clickme1() {
  oil += clicker1;
  document.getElementById("oil").innerHTML = oil;
}

gold = 0;
cps = 0;
autoGs = 0;
employGs = 0;
clicker = 1;
adminGs = 0;

function clickme() {
  gold += clicker;
  document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
}

document.getElementById("cars1").innerHTML = "Car (0) 100 oil and 50 gold";

function automobily() {
  if (oil >= 100 + cars1 && gold >= 50 + cars1) {
    gold -= 50;
    oil -= 100;
    cars1 += 1;
    carcost = 50;
    document.getElementById("oil").innerHTML = oil;
    document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
    document.getElementById("cars1").innerHTML =
      "cars (" + cars1 + ")" + carcost + " 100 oil and 50 gold";
  }
}
```

```html
<big><b><h1>Gold</h1></b></big>

<img src="mince.png" alt="mince" style="width:180px;height:180px;border:0;" onclick="clickme()" />

<h2>
  <bold><big>You have <element id="gold"></element> grams of gold</big></bold>
</h2>

<p id="gold"></p><br><br>

<br></br>
<img src="barel.png" alt="Barel" style="width:200px;height:180px;border:0;" onclick="clickme1()" />

<h2>
  <bold><big>You have <element id="oil"></element> barrels of oil</big></bold>
</h2>

<button onclick="automobily()"><p id="cars1"></p></button>
```

Also:

- Declare variables with `var`, `let` or `const` keywords.
- Put your Js scripts outside of html file

Comment: Your welcome, And thank you for your funny question :D  Good luck man @Holsp